# Where and how do I get all the armor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

To satisfy the dark impulses of completionism in me, I want to look upon my complete hoard of armor and declare "*It is good.*" But first, I need that hoard of armor.

**Where can I find every set of armor?**

Sub-questions:

- Is it possible to own every set of armor in a single play-through?
- What DLC codes do I need to get the bonus armor, if any?
- Are there sub-pieces of armor (like helmets, boots, etc.) I would also need to collect to have a full set? If so, where are those?

Comment: This seems too broad to be effective as a question here, you basically are looking for an entire chapter of a strategy guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be possible to get all the armors in one play through.  You would probably need to focus all your credits on armors though, and forgo upgrading weapons and purchasing weapon mods.

The 5 unique armors cost 250000 together. That's the same as a single Black Widow, and I was able to purchase one of those and upgrade nearly every weapon to level 5 in one play through.

The unique armors are available in the Citadel shops.  But I wouldn't buy them for any other reason than to get the achievement.  You can usually build a better setup using the individual components.  Shepard is also 89% cooler without a helmet.

The individual armor components can be found in missions, or in the Citadel shops if you miss them.  They tend to cost in the 2000-5000 credit range.  There are 35 different components you can collect, so look to spend another 200K.

There are two additional unique armors that you can acquire.  The Reckoner Armor requires you to have played the demo of Kingdoms of Amalur.  The N7 Defender armor came with certain pre-orders.

Comment: Nice. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I only got my Shepard up to 74% cooler. What armour pieces are you using? What about sunglasses and tattoos?