# Where do I find the Inferno (Iron Man) armor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I want to be one cool dude like Tony Stark. Fortunately, I heard through the grapevine that there's a perfect set of armor to satisfy this desire. I know there was a set that looked a lot like Iron Man in Mass Effect 2, and apparently they brought this forward into Mass Effect 3.

**Where do I find the Inferno / "Iron Man" armor?** Can you pick it up for free on a mission, or do you have to buy it from the store? If I have to go the store route, how many credits will the armor set of future set me back?

(*I... am... Iron Man...*)

Comment: Isn't this already covered by [your other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57012/where-and-how-do-i-get-all-the-armor)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Inferno Armor is a "complete set" armor, (so you can't mix and match armor pieces) which is only available to purchase.  Kassa Fabrications stocks it for 50,000 credits, or you can buy it off the terminal in the Normandy's shuttle bay for 10% more.